# Access WordPress database

Tags: wordpress

How to access WordPress database after installation on standalone server?
Is there any plugin available to access that? I have installed WordPress on my digital ocean server and want to write own rest API using WordPress database.

I also read an article provided by WordPress [WordPress wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) which provide a class to access the database. But this class is in php. I want to use in different languages. How should I do that?

Comment: do you want to export database or just want to make an api?

Comment: The database is a standard MySQL database. You can connect to it in any way you usually connect to MySQL databases. You only need the correct server name/database name/username/password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have FTP access or can use Wordpress or a plugin to access its config files, you can open wp-config.php in a text editor and copy out the database host, username, password and database name - they are in the first few lines of the file and well commented.

Then use these to connect with another sql client / database driver / language / etc (assuming your database allows remote connections).

Answer (score 0):

Just get Database name, db user and db pass. Then you can use the database from any language.

If you don't want to do that much work, you can simply use REST API to read data from WordPress.

[WP Rest API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/)